# No File was submitted while trying to make a POST. Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a "POST", but the problem is that I get a "no file was submitted error" and I don't know why.

in my **models.py**

I don't have "icon" in *PersonalDetail*

*PersonalDetailSample*

```
class PersonalDetailSample(models.Model): 
    ...
    icon = models.FileField(_('icon'), db_index=True, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files/')
    ...
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PersonalDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    icon = serializers.FileField(source='details_sample.icon')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetail
        fields = (
            ..., 'icon', ...
        )
```

and in my **views.py**

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    preview_text, preview_name = personal_details.find_text_name(serializer.validated_data)
    serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user,
                    details_sample=serializer.validated_data['details_sample'],
                    content=serializer.validated_data['content'],
                    preview_name=preview_name)
```

The post I would like to do:

```
{
    "checked":true,
    "content": {
        "text_field_1": {
            "size":"small",
            "text":"My userdefined Title",
            "title":"Title"
        },
        "text_field_2": {
            "size":"big",
            "text":"I don't have inspiration",
            "title":"Nachricht"
        }
    },
    "details_sample":27,
    "preview_user_title": "This is my User Title"
}
```

And I get this error: (400 Bad Request)

> {
>     "icon": [
>       "No file was submitted."
>     ]
>   }

And I don't know why...

Maybe someone had the same trouble.

Comment: Does this error raise from the `is_valid` method? where is your file from the post?

Comment: it doesn't enter in the "perform create" method

Comment: Yes, `serializer.is_valid()`  is before `perform_create()`. You didn't post a file in the request.

Comment: Oh. The file is uploaded in the Admin Site in PersonalDetailSample and I wanted just show it in Personal Detail (GET). I don't want to upload it in the Post request since it should take it from PersonalDetailSample. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? (Thanks for your answers :) )

Comment: Okay, set your icon field read only.

Comment: I already tried and in the **GET** call I get this error ```ValueError: The 'icon' attribute has no file associated with it.``` and in the **POST** call I get this one ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte``` (using this code: ```icon = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='details_sample.icon')'```)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139415/discussion-between-guinner-and-chuck-aguilar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using required=False on serializer, or if you don't need to write at all on the file using the rest api use read_only=True.

required=False option http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required

```
class PersonalDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    icon = serializers.FileField(source='details_sample.icon', required=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetail
        fields = (
            ..., 'icon', ...
        )
```

OR read_only option
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only

```
class PersonalDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    icon = serializers.FileField(source='details_sample.icon', read_only=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetail
        fields = (
            ..., 'icon', ...
        )
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks buddy!